# Список процессов пользователя

Tags: linux, командная-строка

> Напишите команду, которая выводит все запущенные процессы пользователя root в файл "user_root_ps".

```
ps -U root -u root u > user_root_ps
```

так правильно?

Comment: ps -U root -u root u > user_root_ps, так правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне достаточно вот такой конструкции:

```
ps -u root > user_root_ps
```

Здесь:

**ps** - команда(утилита) просмотра процессов

**-u** - ключ для отображения процессов пользователя

**root** - имя пользовтеля, процессы которого нас интересуют

**>** - перенаправление вывода команды

**user_root_ps** - относительный путь к файлу в который будет перенаправлен вывод

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!